# Establish isomorphism between finite natural numbers and sigma

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I'm here with Coq studying the relations between two types I've defined. The first is something like a finite subset of `nat`, with just three elements:

```
Inductive N3 := zero | one | two.
```

The second is a sigma type with elements satisfying the proposition `{x: nat | x < 3}`. Here's its definition:

```
Definition less_than_3 := {x| x < 3}.
```

I want to prove that these two types are isomorphic. I definied the two functions involved in the following manner:

```
Definition lt3_to_N3 (n: less_than_3) : N3 :=
match n with
  | exist 0 _ => zero
  | exist 1 _ => one
  | exist 2 _ => two
  | exist _ _ => two
end.

Definition N3_to_lt3 (n: N3) : less_than_3 :=
match n with
  | zero => exist _ 0 l_0_3
  | one => exist _ 1 l_1_3
  | two => exist _ 2 l_2_3
end.
```

Where `l_0_3`, `l_1_3`, and `l_2_3` are just axioms:

```
Axiom l_0_3 : 0 < 3.
Axiom l_1_3 : 1 < 3.
Axiom l_2_3 : 2 < 3.
```

I succeed in defining the first part of the isomorphism

```
Definition eq_n3_n3 (n: N3) : lt3_to_N3 (N3_to_lt3 n) = n.
Proof.
by case n.
Defined.
```

But I'm not able to define the other side. Here's what I've done so far:

```
Definition eq_lt3_lt3 (x: less_than_3) : eq x (N3_to_lt3 (lt3_to_N3 x)).
Proof.
case: x.
move=> n p.
simpl.
???
```

I'm not sure at all about the rest of the definition. I also tried to pattern-match on `x` and on `(N3_to_lt3 (lt3_to_N3 x))`, but I'm not sure about what to return.

```
Definition eq_lt3_lt3 (x: less_than_3) : eq x (N3_to_lt3 (lt3_to_N3 x)) :=
match N3_to_lt3 (lt3_to_N3 x) with
  | x => ???
end.
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with something like

```
Definition eq_lt3_lt3 (x: lt3) : eq x (N3_to_lt3 (lt3_to_N3 x)).
Proof.
destruct x as [ n h ].
destruct n as [ | [ | [ | p ]]]; simpl in *.
```

At this point you'll have goals like:

```
exist (fun x : nat => x < 3) 0 h = exist (fun x : nat => x < 3) 0 l_0_3
```

Basically the only difference now is that you have "some proof that 0 < 3 named `h`" on the left hand side and "Your exact proof that 0 < 3 named `l_0_3`" on the right hand side.

So you'll have to look in the direction of *proof irrelevant / uniqueness of identity proofs* (which is provable over nat & lt).

Comment: Since you seem to use ssreflect, I recall there is something in there std lib to solve exactly this problem, but I don't remember the exact name ...

Comment: I've tried to do so and, for now, to state the uniqueness as axioms: https://pastebin.com/x3CgPUSH . The proof seems correct, but I find eventually myself in a difficult case. Coq asks me to prove `exist (fun x : nat => x < 3) (S (S (S p))) h = exist (fun x : nat => x < 3) 2 l_2_3`, but this is an impossible case. How can I solve that?

Comment: Don't you have a contradiction in your hypothesis ? In the last case you should have something like `h : S (S (S p)) < 3` laying around. I'm pretty sure you know how to derive `False` for this statement ;)

Comment: For the uniquess part, you can have a look at `le_unique` in the `Peano_dec` module.

Comment: Thank you, I finally got it!

Answer (score 3):

You can also have some fun if you profit from the finType machinery in math-comp.

For example, you can use the enumeration of ordinals [isomorphic to your type] to prove your lemma by enumerating all the values instead of doing cumbersome cases:

```
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect.

Set Implicit Arguments.
Unset Strict Implicit.
Unset Printing Implicit Defensive.

Lemma falseP T : false -> T.
Proof. by []. Qed.

Inductive N3 := zero | one | two.

Definition lt3_to_N3 (n: 'I_3) : N3 :=
  match n with
  | Ordinal 0 _ => zero
  | Ordinal 1 _ => one
  | Ordinal 2 _ => two
  | Ordinal _ f => falseP _ f
  end.

Definition N3_to_lt3 (n: N3) : 'I_3 :=
  match n with
  | zero => @Ordinal 3 0 erefl
  | one  => @Ordinal 3 1 erefl
  | two  => @Ordinal 3 2 erefl
  end.

Lemma eq_lt3_lt3 : cancel lt3_to_N3 N3_to_lt3.
Proof.
apply/eqfunP; rewrite /FiniteQuant.quant0b /= /pred0b cardE /enum_mem.
by rewrite unlock /= /ord_enum /= !insubT.
Qed.

(* We can define an auxiliary lemma to make our proofs cleaner *)
Lemma all_by_enum (T : finType) (P : pred T) :
  [forall x, P x] = all P (enum T).
Proof.
apply/pred0P/allP => /= H x; first by have/negbFE := H x.
suff Hx : x \in enum T by exact/negbF/H.
by rewrite mem_enum.
Qed.

Lemma eq_lt3_lt3' : cancel lt3_to_N3 N3_to_lt3.
Proof.
by apply/eqfunP; rewrite all_by_enum enumT unlock /= /ord_enum /= !insubT.
Qed.
```

As you can see, the current design of math-comp is not super well-suited to do this job, but it is fun to get to know the library a bit more nonetheless.

Another fun exercise is to define the `finType` instance for your custom datatype and then establish that both sets have the same cardinality! There are many lemma combinations to try here so you will have fun!

Comment: This seems a bit more complicated. I'll try to go through your proof, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using ssreflect, the easiest route is to use the computational definition of `<` (in `ssrnat`), and then apply the `val_inj` lemma:

```
From mathcomp Require Import ssreflect ssrfun ssrbool eqtype ssrnat.

Inductive N3 := zero | one | two.

Definition less_than_3 := {x| x < 3}.

Definition lt3_to_N3 (n: less_than_3) : N3 :=
match n with
  | exist 0 _ => zero
  | exist 1 _ => one
  | exist 2 _ => two
  | exist _ _ => two
end.

Definition N3_to_lt3 (n: N3) : less_than_3 :=
match n with
  | zero => exist _ 0 erefl
  | one => exist _ 1 erefl
  | two => exist _ 2 erefl
end.

Lemma eq_lt3_lt3 (x: less_than_3) : eq x (N3_to_lt3 (lt3_to_N3 x)).
Proof.
by apply: val_inj; case: x => [[| [|[|x]]] Px].
Qed.
```

The statement of `val_inj` is a bit complicated, but the basic idea is simple: for any boolean predicate `P` on a type `T`, the canonical projection `{ x : T | P x = true } -> T` is injective.  As Vinz put it, this relies on boolean equalities being proof irrelevant; that is, any two proofs of an equality between booleans are themselves equal.  Because of that, equality on `{x | P x = true}` is entirely determined by the element `x`; the proof component is irrelevant.

Comment: I suggest to use the definition of `bijective` in ssrflect, which in turn depends on `cancel`.